# Can't show the popup completely

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a popup in one of my icon and there's a problem with it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKNdb.png

The popup is not showing completely and I've tried z-index but still not working.Can anyone help me with this?Thanks in advance.

This is the code for the popup in the above image.

```
<style>
.hidden {display:none}
</style>

<script>
function showpopup_upms() {
    document.getElementById("popupwindow_upms").classList.toggle("hidden");
}
</script>

<span class="profile"><img src="./sites/default/files/Logo.png" style="margin-top: 30px;" onclick="showpopup_upms()"></span>
<h5 style="color: black;">Settings</h5>
<div id="popupwindow_upms" class="hidden">
<p style="border-style: dotted;color:white;background:black;position:relative;z-index:3;height:100px;">Settings short explanation</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got problem if `z-index` can't working, you can try a more `z-index` number.

 I try added css like that if you used `z-index: 3`.
 Then you need a `display:block` if will completely popup view.

**Added css**

```
.popupwindow_upms {
z-index: 1060;
display: block;
}
```

**Example**

```css
body {
background: #efefef;
}
.popupwindow_upms {
    z-index: 1060;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<style>
.hidden {display:none}
</style>
<script>
function showpopup_upms() {  document.getElementById("popupwindow_upms").classList.toggle("hidden");
}
</script>
<body>
<span class="profile"><img src="./sites/default/files/Logo.png" style="margin-top: 30px;" onclick="showpopup_upms()"></span>
<h5 style="color: black;">Settings</h5>
<div id="popupwindow_upms" class="hidden">
<p class="popupwindow_upms" style="border-style: dotted;color:white;background:black;position:relative;z-index:3;height:100px;">Settings short explanation</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, To Can't show the popup completely

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title> 
        Pop-up Box type Confirm Box 
    </title> 
    <style> 
        h1 { 
            color: green; 
        } 
    </style> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <center> 
        <h3>Confirm Box</h3> 
        <button onclick="geekConfirm()"> 
          Click here for Confirm box 
        </button> 
        <p id="Box"></p> 
        <!-- Confirm box function -->
        <script> 
            function geekConfirm() { 
                var x; 
                if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) { 
                    x = "OK pressed!"; 
                } else { 
                    x = "Cancel!"; 
                } 
                document.getElementById("Box").innerHTML = x; 
            } 
        </script> 
    </center> 
</body> 
</html>
```

I hope this code will be useful to you.

Thank you.

Comment: I think he's got a problem with css because `z-index` can't working

Comment: I agree with that too..i think I'm having problem with the css and I'm not sure why my z-index is not working..my small popup box can't being shown completely.